# How to choose right function from RDKit to calculate atomic RMSD?

Tags: python, rdkit, cheminformatics

I have two conformers of molecule in .xyz files, so i need to calculate the atomic RMSD.
And two methods from RDKit 2023.03.2 (python 3.10.12) gave me a different results:

```py
from rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles import MolFromXYZFile
from rdkit.Chem.AllChem import GetBestRMS, AlignMol

mol1 = MolFromXYZFile('mol1.xyz')
mol2 = MolFromXYZFile('mol2.xyz')

print(GetBestRMS(mol1, mol2))
# output:
>>> 1.4724067538388081

print(AlignMol(mol1, mol2))
# output:
>>> 1.6849895064063607
```

Also I tried another [tool](https://github.com/charnley/rmsd) and obtained same results as `AlignMol`.

```bash
calculate_rmsd mol1.xyz mol2.xyz
>>> 1.68498950637163
```

Which result is more presentable and why?

Order of atoms is same in both files.
Input files:

```
53
mol1
C -1.2878 0.5763 2.5081
C -0.0940 0.1341 1.9360
C 1.1741 0.0622 2.6960
C 2.4687 0.3699 2.3374
C 3.5742 0.1850 3.3022
C 3.2088 -0.3028 4.6335
C 4.1333 -0.5219 5.6874
C 3.7003 -0.9868 6.9197
C 2.3568 -1.2459 7.1454
C 1.4287 -1.0423 6.1369
C 1.8659 -0.5789 4.9095
C -0.1188 -0.2426 0.5911
C -1.2905 -0.1922 -0.1478
C -2.4894 0.1923 0.4610
C -2.4687 0.5937 1.7888
O -3.6751 0.1816 -0.2061
O 0.8942 -0.4005 3.9555
O 4.7477 0.4131 3.0421
O 5.4703 -0.2990 5.5706
O 1.9479 -1.7025 8.3635
H -3.7342 -0.5414 -0.8759
H 0.7834 -0.5858 0.0965
H -1.3083 0.9226 3.5342
H 5.7190 0.0308 4.6726
H 4.4198 -1.1495 7.7154
H 0.9693 -1.8444 8.3853
H 0.3762 -1.2432 6.3074
C 3.2716 2.0790 0.6209
C 2.6150 2.5024 -0.7279
H 3.0594 2.8509 1.3592
C 5.1937 1.8062 -0.8108
C 3.4610 3.5968 -1.3656
H 1.6216 2.8999 -0.5251
C 4.9268 3.0978 -1.5712
H 4.6973 0.9805 -1.3186
H 3.0327 3.8733 -2.3278
H 5.6075 3.8633 -1.2015
O 2.6447 0.8584 1.0546
O 4.6471 1.9473 0.5163
O 2.4942 1.3966 -1.6177
H 2.0475 1.6913 -2.4495
O 3.4694 4.7317 -0.5048
H 4.0197 5.4470 -0.9094
O 5.1997 2.8790 -2.9520
H 6.1446 2.6081 -3.0614
C 6.6626 1.4789 -0.6410
H 7.0930 1.2618 -1.6264
H 6.7632 0.5731 -0.0304
O 7.4024 2.5363 -0.0454
H 8.3513 2.2694 0.0342
H -3.3856 0.9228 2.2665
O -1.2365 -0.5216 -1.4668
H -1.8719 -0.0059 -2.0191
```

```
53
mol2
C -1.0014821846 0.9626299172 2.5573785856
C 0.0496599188 0.3470275666 1.8824250702
C 1.3056173719 0.0052166453 2.5515440934
C 2.5351322319 0.0505765352 1.9720897612
C 3.7184917469 -0.3826176514 2.6867783559
C 3.5033977186 -0.7447874668 4.0680019924
C 4.5710689863 -1.1496900096 4.909962476
C 4.331012171 -1.4643148376 6.2323969408
C 3.0322050126 -1.3853039034 6.7309438348
C 1.9606405974 -0.9976519507 5.9352251045
C 2.2200803246 -0.6844866633 4.6126606673
C -0.0528746879 0.1344520608 0.507116763
C -1.1219184368 0.628333423 -0.1989442937
C -2.1750118806 1.258326425 0.4749709536
C -2.1156576788 1.3988437299 1.8542332231
O -3.2301270978 1.7355182031 -0.214346733
O 1.1556575067 -0.3281667805 3.8507217244
O 4.8279324073 -0.4347069578 2.1341908715
O 5.8133601226 -1.2251560697 4.434103765
O 2.8666906888 -1.7097569209 8.0310352514
H -3.0713245174 1.5796359161 -1.1554400192
H 0.7299831889 -0.3731461741 -0.0302850043
H -0.9388459439 1.1233243801 3.6248068287
H 5.7859501611 -0.9769864865 3.4829713595
H 5.1419673986 -1.7725754551 6.8757055943
H 1.9400722545 -1.62970029 8.2788987003
H 0.9493477107 -0.9458446957 6.3149706343
C 2.5307872509 1.7951110049 0.3561613886
C 2.3639651114 1.9388506917 -1.1814462985
H 1.6479610269 2.1607641485 0.879358051
C 4.8869466139 2.2418290229 0.3490523926
C 3.6720879214 2.3746048635 -1.8740440416
H 1.6401825681 2.7355051455 -1.3532583007
C 4.8654555682 1.7945686214 -1.1212738445
H 5.2822036245 1.4119392135 0.942689672
H 3.6552784387 1.9153847486 -2.8655390874
H 5.7929240643 2.1157036397 -1.6054301121
O 2.7255144868 0.4227796783 0.6686915653
O 3.5825033241 2.5760176524 0.833928119
O 1.8260857813 0.7731060515 -1.7765584379
H 2.5260815562 0.1043987317 -1.7561092302
O 3.7348130031 3.7633538109 -2.0506663046
H 4.3080557405 4.1705571602 -1.3821917325
O 4.7612665245 0.3796800179 -1.2361215032
H 4.7275141397 -0.0164450412 -0.3543935804
C 5.7429738789 3.4584223359 0.6600871543
H 6.7326676961 3.3376535301 0.2210362026
H 5.8537268537 3.5374523689 1.7445044248
O 5.1975857627 4.658562741 0.1413912577
H 4.3744067965 4.8217632085 0.6175036702
H -2.9382623189 1.8891314043 2.3568277443
O -1.2092892555 0.5529415687 -1.5558948255
H -0.3106612492 0.4735711915 -1.9168208442
```

Comment: You haven't provided us with sufficient information to help.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: compare https://www.rdkit.org/docs/cppapi/namespaceRDKit_1_1MolAlign.html#a361135eb57a968f422b75ffd00180e3f vs https://www.rdkit.org/docs/cppapi/namespaceRDKit_1_1MolAlign.html#a2ba3958b30c3ed26a8117205ae5a6abd

Answer (score 0):

This may help

Key Differences

Alignment: AllChem.AlignMol() actually modifies the coordinates of the target molecule to align it to the reference molecule. In contrast, AllChem.GetBestRMS() doesn't modify the molecules; it only calculates the best achievable RMSD.

Optimization: AllChem.GetBestRMS() tries to find the optimal (minimum) RMSD by evaluating multiple alignments, while AllChem.AlignMol() only performs a single alignment.

Output: AllChem.AlignMol() returns the RMSD after aligning, which may not be the minimum possible RMSD. AllChem.GetBestRMS() returns the minimum RMSD possible between the two conformers.

Because of these differences, you may find that the RMSD values differ when using these two functions. If you first align the molecules using AllChem.AlignMol() and then calculate RMSD using AllChem.GetBestRMS(), you're likely to get a more accurate measure of how similar the two structures are.